# Problem understanding a theorem on the partitions of integers.

Tags: combinatorics, integer-partitions

So, we saw the following theorem on the partitions of integers:

a) The number of distinct vectors $(n_1,...,n_r)$ of positive integers (i.e $n_1,..,n_r > 0$) satisfying $n_1 + ... + n_r = n $ is $${n-1\choose r-1}$$

b) The number of distinct vectors $(n_1,...,n_r)$ of non-negative integers (i.e $n_1,..,n_r \geq 0$) satisfying $n_1 + ... + n_r = n $ is $${n+r-1\choose n}$$

I tried approaching this theorem using the stars and bars representation.

The way I understand b) is the following. Suppose we have $n$ stars which are lined up, and we want to create $r$ groups by placing separators (thus we need $r-1$ separators). Here, we ask ourselves: "How many ways are there to form $r$ groups?" We can answer this the following way. First we can choose where to place the separators, then place the stars. There is ${n+r-1\choose r-1}$ ways to place the separators and $1$ way to place the stars (since they are indistinguishable). Thus, by the multiplication principle, the number of ways to form $r$ groups is  ${n+r-1\choose r-1} \cdot 1$  (which is the same as ${n+r-1\choose n}$, as we could have placed the stars first and then the separators).

My problem is when I try to find a similar explanation for a). The way I see it is that since $n_i > 0 $ for all $i=1,..,r$, this means that I cannot have two bars without any stars in between them (i.e we are forming $r$ groups, but with the condition that each group must contain at least one star). I do not understand how I could count the number of ways I can form $r$ groups (where each group contains at least one star) nor why this number is equal to ${n-1\choose r-1}$

Comment: You have the $n$ stars lined up ahead of time.  Then, you pick $r-1$ of the *gaps* between the stars *simultaneously* and *without repetition* to place the bars.  There are $n-1$ gaps *between* the stars and you pick $r-1$ of them.  In doing so, the stars before the first bar will be in the first group.  The stars between the first bar and the second bar are the second group and so on...  By choosing without repetition here like we did, we guarantee that each group has at least one star in it.

Comment: Alternatively, you can use the other of the two explanations you are comfortable with and then use a change of variable to put it into the form you prefer, e.g. by letting $(m_1,m_2,\dots,m_r)=(n_1-1,n_2-1,\dots,n_r-1)$

Comment: The [Wikipedia page for stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)&oldid=824240954#Proofs_via_the_method_of_stars_and_bars) gives explanations for these theorems as well.

Comment: @JMoravitz I got it, thank you. Indeed,  by choosing without repetition here like you did, you guarantee that each group has at least one star in it. Did not think about this. Thank you very much

Comment: Note for (b) ${n+r-1\choose n} = {n+r-1\choose r-1}$ which you can read as having $n+r-1$ stars and bars positions and you have to choose $r-1$ of them to be bars; any will do.  Then for (a) the bars' positions are more restricted: you have $n-1$ potential positions between the $n$ stars and you again have to choose $r-1$ for the bars

Comment: @Henry Yes, thank you. It seems much more clear now.

Comment: @JMoravitz Can you explain how that would work? If $m_i=n_i-1$ and we consider the equivalent problem of counting solutions in $\sum m_i=n+r$ for nonnegative $m_i$ then by the other part this has $\tbinom {n+2r-1}{n+r}$ solutions. Or am I missing something.

Comment: @Shahab If $m_i=n_i-1$, then $\sum m_i = n_1-1+n_2-1+n_3-1+\dots+n_r-1=(n_1+n_2+\dots+n_r)-(1+1+\dots+1)=n-r$, not $n+r$.  We would have by the other part $\binom{(n-r)+r-1}{(n-r)}$ which simplifies to $\binom{n-1}{n-r}$, which further simplifies remembering $\binom{a}{b}=\binom{a}{a-b}$ to be $\binom{n-1}{(n-1)-(n-r)}=\binom{n-1}{r-1}$ as desired.

Comment: @JMoravitz Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** put one star in each of the $r$ areas separated by the $r-1$ bars, then count how many ways you can place the remainging $n-r$ stars in the $r$ areas.

Comment: I got it, thank you. Basically, this way is the same doing a change of variable.

Comment: If you mean that everywhere we see an $n$, we replace it with $n-r$, then yes.